# CAPS LOCK shuts down the computer immediately

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, keyboard, shutdown

I have discovered this problem with my Laptop, today itself. No matter what the environment, app, screen is, as soon as I press **CAPS LOCK** key, the computer shuts itself down abruptly (abnormal shutdown, like power failure).

It can again be turned on normally though, using power button.

I Googled a bit and discovered that CAPS LOCK is used as CRUISE control so it shuts down the laptop in-case it is not cool enough. My laptop is cool enough.

Following are the environments, in which I've tested this abnormal behavior of CAPS LOCK (abruptly shutting down my machine)

1. GRUB
2. UBUNTU 16.04
3. System Testing (F12)
4. Windows 8
5. Pressing CAPS LOCK on on-screen keyboard
6. External Keyboard's CAPS LOCK

My laptop is **Dell Inspiron 3542**. Thanks

Comment: `CAPS LOCK is used as CRUISE control` - could you share a link?

Comment: You can disable your Caps-Lock Key.. May be it will help.

Comment: Put sunglasses on your computer, and then at last it will be cool enough.  Note: This really looks like a great subtle troll based on an old 4chan.org meme from the 2000's when /b/ was good and doesn't afraid of anything.  http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/caps-lock

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. In my case keyboard replacement in laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad T420) solved the problem.

Comment: You also had your laptop shut down when hitting capslock? When the keyboard was replaced, did they indicate what was wrong with the old one that caused the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have a dual boot computer and both Windows 10 and Ubuntu have the same problem... touch the Caps Lock and you instantly shut off the computer.  I had to start up RegEdit and go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
There I had to a enter a "Scancode Map" and put in the following 00000000 00000000 02000000 00003A00 00000000.   That disabled my caps lock key completely.

However that did nothing for my Ubuntu 17.04.  There, I had to set up enter the following in the .bashrc and then in the Startup Menu (both).>> Setxkbmap -option '' -option 'ctrl:nocaps'

With that I was able to disable the caps lock completely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by enabling **Toggle Keys**? I don't know if this will prevent the laptop form shutting down but I have other kind of issues using the Caps Lock and by enabling it solves some problem. There's nothing wrong to try. Please follow these steps:

1. **Open Ease of Access Center**, by typing it on the search bar.
2. Now click **Make the keyboard easier to use**, this will open a window.
3. Check **Turn on Toggle Keys** option.